# extracting n words out of a string in bourne shell

Tags: unix, sh

I want to extract specific number of words form a string.

For example: `s1= "Hello: I am new to this forum"`

How can I extract first 4 words `"Hello: I am new"` out of the string?

Comment: Bourne shell, or POSIX shell?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this;

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="Hello: I am new to this forum"
echo $s1 | cut -d' ' -f-4
```

-d' ' : use space for field delimeter
-f-4  : field 4 and before

> man cut ;
>
> ```
>    -d, --delimiter=DELIM
>           use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
>
>    -f, --fields=LIST
>           select only these fields;  also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
> ```

with awk solution ;

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="Hello: I am new to this forum"
echo $s1 | awk  '{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}'
```

or only echo;

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="Hello: I am new to this forum"
echo ${s1/%\ to*/}
```

with sed ;

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="Hello: I am new to this forum"
echo $s1 | sed -E 's/(([^ ]+ ){4}).*/\1/'
```